# With a Comparer to comparer keys by their values from a dictionary, SortedDictionary always throw exception

Tags: c#, sortedlist, sorteddictionary

I want to achieve a heap with SortedDictionary which compares values instead of keys. My elements are in the dictionary and I added them one by one to the SortedDictionary. It always thow exception at the 2nd time from the "Add" method in the loop. "An entry with the same key already exists".
Since I got elements from a dictionary, I know that keys cannot be same. What should I do to make such a SortedDictionary work?
Thanks a lot!

```
dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var sort = new SortedDictionary<int, int>(Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => dic[x].CompareTo(dic[y])));
foreach (var pair in dic)
{
    sort.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @SylvainLIU. What `Values` (not `Keys`) does dictionary `dic` contain? Are they unique? Dictionary `dic` must also contain unique values to make this code work without throwing an exception, because your code uses values from `dic` to compare keys that are inserted into `sort`.

Comment: Thanks Iliar. You're right in the Dictionary the values are not unique. Do you know how could I make the SortedDictionary work in such senorio? I want it sorted according to the values, which could be not unique.

Comment: Do you want `sort` to contain keys of the `dic` but being sorted by the values of the `dic`? If values are the same how keys must be ordered? For example, `dic` contains two pairs (1, 3) and (2, 3). How keys 2 and 3 must be ordered? In any order?

Comment: Yes. Keys can be ordered descending or ascending if there is a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the next approach:

```
var sort = new SortedDictionary<int, int>(
    Comparer<int>.Create(
        (x, y) => 
        {
            int vx = dic[x];
            int vy = dic[y];

            // If values are the same then compare keys.
            if (vx == vy)
                return x.CompareTo(y);

            // Otherwise - compare values.
            return vx.CompareTo(vy);
        }));
```

If you declare `sort` using this approach then `Keys` in the `sort` will be ordered by `Values`. Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RcmWHL) that shows how this approach works.

---

@SylvainLIU asked:

> What confuse me is, in my original post, by using
>   dic[x].CompareTo(dic[y]) I meant to get the return value of the
>   Compare() method, but not to take dic[x] or dic[y] as Key of the
>   SortedDictionary. Why they're asked to be unique?

You were right and your sample worked as you assumed. So why did it throw an exception?

`SortedDictionary` must contain unique keys. By specifying `Comparer` for `SortedDictionary` we specify how to order keys and how to define if a new key is unique. If `Comparer` returns `0` for a new key then this key is not unique and an exception `An entry with the same key already exists` will be thrown.

If we use comparer `dic[x].CompareTo(dic[y])` then to compare keys `x` and `y` we use their values `dic[x]` and `dic[y]`. For example, lets we have two pairs `(Key=1, Value=3)` and `(Key=2, Value=3)`. If we use comparer `dic[x].CompareTo(dic[y])` to compare them, then keys of this pairs are not unique, because they are compared by their values: `3.CompareTo(3) = 0`. Of course, values `1` and `2` are different numbers, but from the point of view of comparer `dic[x].CompareTo(dic[y])` they are the same. Therefore if we use this comparer we must ensure that values of the pairs must be unique to prevent duplicate errors.

If we use next comparer

```
int vx = dic[x];
int vy = dic[y];

// If values are the same then compare keys.
if (vx == vy)
    return x.CompareTo(y);

// Otherwise - compare values.
return vx.CompareTo(vy);
```

then values of the `dic` must not be unique, because this comparer takes into account that values in `dic` can be the same and for this case it uses another strategy to ordering and checking for uniqueness.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks for your time Iliar, and for pointing out that values should be unique for Compare method. It's already great help for me. Just I'm not quiet clear about why Compare works this way. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: What do you concretly want to know by asking `why Compare works this way`? Here is documentation of the [`Comparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) class and its method [`Compare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1.compare?view=netframework-4.8). If you don't find answers to your questions in the documentation fell free to ask them here.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: I didn't get my answer.. What confuse me is, in my original post, by using `dic[x].CompareTo(dic[y])` I meant to get the return value of the `Compare()` method, but not to take `dic[x]` or `dic[y]` as Key of the SortedDictionary. Why they're asked to be unique?

Comment: @SylvainLIU I extended my post to answer your question. Please, check it. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Iliar, really appreciate that you make it so clear. Thank you so much!